# Execution order of if else issue

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have function, a part of it works non-correct.

What i need -

1) if `window width < 768 (do smth)` 
2) if `window width = 768 (do smth)` 
3) `else (do smth)`

There is a part of function

```
var windowWid = $(window).width();
if ($poselok.length > 0) {
    if (windowWid === 768) {
        var offset = 0.05;
    }
    if (windowWid < 768) {
        var offset = 0 - $el_full.offset().left - el_margin_left;
    } else {
        var offset = 0 - $el_full.offset().left + $sideLeft + 15;
    }
} else {
    var offset = 0 - $el_full.offset().left - el_margin_left;
};
```

Without     `if (windowWid < 768)` condition `if (windowWid === 768)` works, but with it - doesn't.

I tried `if (windowWid < 767)` and `if (windowWid <= 767)` to separate `if` but nothing.

I tried replace `if`, `(windowWid === 768)` works but `if (windowWid < 768)` works incorrect.

I think i have mistake in Execution order, but don't know how to fix it.

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (condition1) {
    block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
} else if (condition2) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
} else {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this should fix the issue, but I believe for some reason, the second if is executed as well. Try changing the code as follows:

```
var windowWid = $(window).width();
if ($poselok.length > 0) 
{
    if (windowWid === 768) 
    {
        var offset = 0.05;
    }
    else if (windowWid < 768) 
    {
        var offset = 0 - $el_full.offset().left - el_margin_left;
    } 
    else 
    {
        var offset = 0 - $el_full.offset().left + $sideLeft + 15;
    }
} 
else 
{
    var offset = 0 - $el_full.offset().left - el_margin_left;
}
```